# variable value in file path in execute SQL Task in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to use `Execute SQL task` in SSIS. but its not accepting variable value in path? The file name is dynamic so, it has to come from variable. The below code is direct input in Execute SQL task.

```
USE [master]
go

RESTORE DATABASE MyDb FROM
DISK = N'c:\DBRestores\?'
WITH REPLACE

go
```

then I used, `Parameter Mapping` to map that value but the task is failing.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Try using a variable to dynamically construct the entire SQL string.

Comment: Hi @Tab Alleman, thanks for the reply. I tried to wrap up in dynamic sql but its still not working in SSIS. I want to pass SSIS variable value to T-sql Statement? I think now you got my point. Thanks

Comment: When you tried the dynamic sql, did you change the SQL Source Type to variable?   Can you post a screenshot of the task properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set dynamic parameter in the Expressions. 
In `Execute SQL Task Editor`, goto `Expressions` -> `Property` -> `SQLStatementSource` -> `Expression` and put below SQL there, replace your dynamic variable name in it and click on `Evaluate Expression` and check the Evaluated Value.

```
"USE [master]
go

RESTORE DATABASE MyDb FROM
DISK = N'c:\\DBRestores\\" + @[User::VariableParameter]  + "'
WITH REPLACE

go"
```

If the evaluated value is as expected, then the script would accept dynamic file names from variable.

Comment: Hi @Jigar, thanks for the reply. I will try this and let you know. thanks

Comment: Hi @Jigar, I tried with same process its fine when I check `Evaluate Expression`. the value showing fine but `Execute SQL task` showing 'there were errors during task validation'. and what should I write in `direct input value` in `General Tab` . Because I already used the code in `Expressions ` tab. Thanks

Comment: In General Tab, 

`SQL Source Type:` Direct Input
`SQL Statement:` -- Leave empty -- This will come up automatically from Expression --

Comment: Hi @Jigar, thanks. I tried now here at home in my laptop. its working now. but I will try same this at work tomorrow. if I get any problems I will let you know. thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @Jigar, I tried here at work as well its working fine. Thanks for that. Can you please explain why code is used in `"USE [master]-----go"` Is this dynamic sql? If so why we are not used `exec sp_executesql @SQLStatement;` Thanks.